# Ghost.py - click specific button

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, ghost.py

I'm trying to click specific button but with no result yet.
Using `Python 3.4.2` and `Ghost.py`.

`<a class="button" title="" ref="1" id="details" href="javascript:void(0);">
</a>`

This code is under many `div`'s and `li`'s.

The simplest answer is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate a line of Javascript with Ghost.py and use the `click` method on the appropriate DOM element you get with `getElementById`:

```
page, resources = ghost.evaluate("document.getElementById('details').click();", expect_loading=True)
```

**UPDATE**

---

To get the link by class use the following line

```
ghost.evaluate("document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click();", expect_loading=True)
```

There is another version you can use to select and click the first link with an `ref="1"` attribute on your page:

```
ghost.evaluate("document.querySelector('a[ref="1"]').click();", expect_loading=True)
```

Comment: How do I get DOM element?

Comment: @Fred The Javascript call `document.getElementById('details')` gives you the DOM element with the id `details`.

Comment: What if the id `details` occur many times and the only thing what is unique is `ref="1"` number  and `class="button"` name, which is my case?

Comment: @Fred Then you don't have valid HTML where the id of an element must be unique. See my updated answer for the case of an unique class name, but you should really modify your html to make it valid one otherwise you might run into more problems along the way. Better you give this link an unique id which you use in the call `document.getElementById('your_unique_id_for_this_element').click()`

Comment: Can I pass both arguments `getElementsById` and `getElementsByClassName` at the same time?

"Better you give this link an unique id"
`ref="1"` makes it special. I can't modify html.

Comment: @Fred Usually you only need to use `getElementById` to make something with an unique element on your page. You need a way to select the correct element in your HTML and if you do it with `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName` is your choice.

Comment: @Fred I added another version you can use that selects the first link in your DOM that has a `ref` attribute that has the value `"1"`

Comment: I will learn on that what you wrote, thanks for your valuable input! :)

Comment: @Fred Good to help you and thanks for the warm words :)